# c++ class include undefined reference

Tags: c++, class, object, header, include

I am having a problem constructing an instance of a class in a larger program.

In the main function I have:

```
//main.cpp
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass aMyClass;
//do stuff with MyClass
```

MyClass' header is only a constructor at this point and looks like this:

```
//MyClass.h

class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass();
};
```

MyClass' source then looks like this, again only a constructor at this point:

```
//MyClass.cpp
#include "MyClass.h"

//--CONSTRUCTOR--//
MyClass::MyClass(){
    cout << "constructing MyClass object..." << endl;
}
```

When I try to run my program I get this error:

```
undefined reference to `MyClass::MyClass()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Edit :**
I'm compiling the program with the following commands using the command line:

```
g++ main.cpp -o mainProgram
```

**Edit (solved) :**
The compilation needs to include MyClass.cpp, the correct command is:

```
g++ man.cpp MyClass.cpp -o mainProgram
```

While I'm sure it's something small, where am I slipping up here? I've tried declaring the object earlier in the program, but that did not solve the problem and I got the same error.

Does anyone see a problem here?

Comment: Show your compilation command line, please. It seems you're not linking `MyClass.cpp` when building the executable.

Comment: The code looks fine, but it looks like you're not linking with `MyClass.cpp`. How are you building the program?

Comment: I've updated to include my compilation instructions. See the edit above.

Comment: Try `g++ main.cpp MyClass.cpp -o mainProgram` instead.  Longer term, you'll want to learn about Makefiles or other ways to build multiple-source-file programs.

Comment: is `#include "MyClass.h"` actually inside the main function?  Because that would cause problems

Comment: @user1167662 how else would I link my header to the rest of the program?

Comment: @JoeZ adding MyClass.cpp to the compilation commands took care of it. I'll edit to reflect this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you also need to compile MyClass.cpp - that's where the implementation is.

```
g++ main.cpp MyClass.cpp -o mainProgram
```